# Do I pay a K-1 if I make below $3000 in a year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, schedule-k-1

I received a K-1 from an ETF. I was buying very small amounts of funds, because investing is my hobby. I did not receive any distributions, nor did I make a considerable amount of money. Do I have to pay this to the IRS?

Answer (score 2):

"Generally, any income, capital gain/loss, expense and other items reported to you on the Schedule K-1 must be included in your tax return."
https://www.uscfinvestments.com/k1-information

Think of the K-1 like any 1099 that you receive. You have to figure out how it affects your 1040 (and how it affects your need to file the 1040, if that is in question).

Answer (score 0):

You've invested in a [Publicly Traded Partnership](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/ptp.asp). As a partner you receive a K-1. It should flow to your own tax return (usually through Schedule E) and be added to the rest of your income.

You may have or haven't received any distribution, but it doesn't mean you haven't received any income (which may have been added to your equity in the partnership detailed on Schedule K-1, line L).